# how to obtain a list name through cross-domain CSOM

Tags: cross-domain

how to obtain the list name  through cross-domain CSOM
Provided that I have the list GUID. 
Any easy way for the conversion ?

Comment: Would you share your code please. I think you need to make some ajax calls for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list name from SharePoint using CSOM using below mentioned code.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using SP = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

namespace Microsoft.SDK.SharePointServices.Samples
{
    class RetrieveAllListProperties
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string siteUrl = "http://MyServer/sites/MySiteCollection";

            ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
            Web oWebsite = clientContext.Web;
            ListCollection collList = oWebsite.Lists;

            clientContext.Load(collList);

            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            foreach (SP.List oList in collList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Title: {0} Created: {1}", oList.Title, oList.Created.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you are working with cross domain environment than you must have to use JavaScript. You can get idea from **[Complete basic operations using JavaScript library code in SharePoint 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163201.aspx)**